# What are the valid conditions for zcml:condition?

Tags: zope, zcml

ZCML can include conditional directives of the form

```
<configure zcml:condition="installed some.python.package">
    (conditional configuration directives)
</configure>
```

What is the expression syntax for `condition`? Is 'or' allowed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I always have to look this up too. The syntax is very simple, and `or` is not part of the syntax, I am afraid.

As you can see from [the documentation in the zope.configuration source code](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.configuration/blob/4.0.3/src/zope/configuration/xmlconfig.py#L217-L256), the syntax is always of the form `verb arguments`, where verb is one of `have`, `not-have`, `installed` and `not-installed`.

`have` and `not-have` test for a registered feature. A registered feature is simply an opaque string that has been registered with a `<meta:provides feature="something" />` tag. Use it to flag that something has been included without tying it to a particular implementation. Example:

```
<configure zcml:condition="have apidoc">
    <!-- only when the apidoc feature has been provided -->
</configure>
```

`installed` and `not-installed` simply try to import the named package; if the import succeeds so does the `installed` test. Example:

```
<configure zcml:condition="installed sqlalchemy"> 
    <!-- only when the sqlalchemy module can be imported -->
</configure>
```

Comment: I wrote a component that can use multiple implementations of a crypto function depending on which is installed. For my 'or' I can probably put the same `<meta provides feature="something">` in two zcml:condition blocks and then register my component in a third. Thanks!

Comment: So what about multiple conditions? How does that work?

Comment: @b4oshany: there is no facility to specify multiple conditions on a single tag. You'd have to find a way to nest tags on which to put `zcml:condition` attributes (you can't repeat attributes on a single tag in XML).

Comment: Well, I was thinking about `and` condition. I guess `zcml:condition` doesn't support and condition.

Comment: Exactly, there are no boolean operators, only the syntax I documented in my answer.