# how to make Plone Dexterity container look like Archetypes folder

Tags: plone, dexterity

I've created a Dexterity product that includes container and non-container Dexterity content types.  Having discovered collective.documentviewer (yay! thanks! huzzah!), I'd like to use its dvpdf-group-view, but that is registered in ZCML as being for Folders, and my Dexterity containers don't qualify.  I've looked through the web interfaces available on my container type, added SiteRoot, and that enabled the view to be applied, but is also completely wrong.

I'm confident there's a right way to do this, and I'm pretty sure it's central to the whole adapter/interface mechanism, but I just can't find it in any of the books.

Anyone care to try an explanation?  First, the line or two that would enable a Dexterity container to pretend it's also a Folder; second, how to change the default view of a single instance of a Dexterity type so that it presents a foreign component's view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Register the view for dexterity containers too**

The view is registered for the Archetypes folder interface (`Products.CMFCore.interfaces._content.IFolderish`), but your dexterity container does not provide this interface (but `plone.dexterity.interfaces.IDexterityContainer`).
The reason may be that the product and/or the view is not compatible with dexterity.

Anway, you can try it out yourself by registering the view also for the the `IDexterityContainer` interface by putting a little ZCML in the `configure.zcml` in your package (see also the [Creating a package](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/pre-requisites/creating-a-package) section of the [Dexterity Developer Manual](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/)):

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser">

    <configure package="collective.documentviewer">

        <browser:page
            name="dvpdf-group-view"
            for="plone.dexterity.interfaces.IDexterityContainer"
            class=".views.GroupView"
            template="templates/group-view.pt"
            permission="zope2.View"
            layer=".interfaces.ILayer" />

    </configure>

</configure>
```

The `<browser:page>` is copied from the [collective.documentviewer configure.zcml](https://github.com/collective/collective.documentviewer/blob/master/collective/documentviewer/configure.zcml#L48) but I've changed the interface `for=` to the dexterity container interface, so that the view also works for dexterity containers.

The inner `<configure package="collective.documentviewer">` tells the ZCML parser that the configuration should be applied as if the configure.zcml would be directly in `collective.documentviewer` - this allows you for example to use the original template (otherwise you would have to copy it or do some nasty things).

I did not test it myself: it may still be that the view needs an archetypes container and does not work with a dexterity container. It may also be that you have to register more components from the documentviewer for dexterity containers (maybe the menus? take a look at what is registered in the [original configure.zcml](https://github.com/collective/collective.documentviewer/blob/master/collective/documentviewer/configure.zcml).

If everything works well you should consider doing the changes in collective.documentviewer on [github](https://github.com/collective/collective.documentviewer) directly and make a pull-request to the author (be aware that dexterity is not plone-core yet). But first ask if and how you should do it :-)

**2. Changing the default view**

With plone it is possible to define multiple views for a specific type. The view can then be selected in the display menu per instance of this type. If you open up `http://localhost:8080/Plone/portal_types/manage_main` and click on your type, there is a field `Available view methods`, where you can add the view-name (`dvpdf-group-view`) on a seperate line.

After you create a new object of your type or visit an existing one, you have a "Display"-menu which should list the view. Select it and this object now has this view as default.

(If you want to make the view not selectable on other objects of this type you could just remove it from the type configuration so that it is not selectable anymore - the existing configuration of your object will stay).

Comment: These instructions were perfect -- thank you! I'd seen but forgotten that you could put configuration instructions for a foreign product into your local configure.zcml.

Comment: (Editing timed out.) These instructions were perfect -- thank you! The view now works, and can be flipped on for instances via the promised Display menu.  I'd seen but forgotten that you could put configuration instructions for a foreign product into your local configure.zcml.  I'm happy to make the changes to a copy of collective.documentviewer; am I correct that the functional change is just adding a space delimited "plone.dexterity.interfaces.IDexterityContainer" to the "for" line of the view?  What sort of additional testing against the dexterity container would be required?

Comment: You're welcome :) Adding the IDexterityContainer to the same ZCML-Tag would not work - the for can only contain one single interface in this case (multiple space separated values are possible in other tags such as <adapter>). Adding an additional <browser:view>-tag should do the job - but all dexterity related things should be within a zcml:condition="installed plone.app.dexterity" (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596611/what-are-the-valid-conditions-for-zcmlcondition) on zcml conditions), so that it still works without dexterity but archetypes.

Comment: I suggest to get in touch with the author of collective.documentviewer how it should be done. Maybe it would be enough to just use non-archetypes-specific interface in collective.documentviewer, which is provided by both, archetypes- and dexterity-containers. `OFS.interfaces.IFolder` should work.