# Making an addon both Plone 4 and Plone 5 compatible

Tags: plone

I'm trying to make an addon both Plone 4 and Plone 5 compatible.  The problem I'm running into is the profiles/default XML.

Plone 5: I have a registry.xml for registering CSS
Plone 4: I have a cssregistry.xml for registering CSS

I was hoping Plone 4 would ignore the registry.xml but it picked it up and then crashes during the install in Plone 4.  Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have multiple profiles pointing to different profile directories (they are defined in `configure.zcml`), and the Plone docs [have examples of how to conditionally evaluate ZCML](http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/components/zcml.html#id6):

```
<include zcml:condition="have plone-4" package=".package" />
<include zcml:condition="not-have plone-4" package=".otherpackage" />
```

There's also a straight "evaluate content if condition is met" by [having `zcml:condition` on a configure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1600381/505649).

Comment: I commonly not use separate subpackages, but you can use the same approach for registering an alternative profiles. Example: https://github.com/RedTurtle/TurtledGazette/blob/94fa38cc0b877a30cd8aec592aeea1ef553cb8a3/Products/PloneGazette/profiles.zcml#L16

Comment: Is there a similar condition for plone 5 then?  that would be safer

Comment: @Danimal: [plone.app.mosaic](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.mosaic/blob/master/src/plone/app/mosaic/browser/configure.zcml) seems to use `have plone-5`, but I have no Plone 5 here to double-check.

Comment: Watch out: 'have plone-4' will be true on both Plone 4 and Plone 5.  See https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/5.0/Products/CMFPlone/meta.zcml#L13. So you should use 'have plone-5' and 'not-have plone-5'.

Answer (score 0):

What you said works great when you add:

```
xmlns:zcml="http://namespaces.zope.org/zcml"
```

To the top configuration.  Just a note for any future people who need this.